# Resolve inner promise too

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I need to a write custom `promise`.I have tried as shown below.But the problem is how to get the `recommendationCacheUrls` value after the inner promise also resolved? i.e. `fileTransfer.download` promise.

```
setNewCacheUrls(providedUrls: any, nativeURL: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let recommendationCacheUrls = [];
    _.forEach(providedUrls, (url) => {
        const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        fileTransfer.download(url.url, nativeURL + url.name).then((entry) => {
           recommendationCacheUrls.push({ name: url.name, url: entry.toURL() });
                }, (error) => {
            console.error('error: ' + error);
        });
    });
    resolve(recommendationCacheUrls);
});
```

}

Comment: rather than using `forEach` with `push` - use a combination of `map` and `Promise.all` - then you wont have to write a custom promise implementation that is not PromiseA+ compliant

Comment: you could also `resolve(Promise.all(recommendationCacheUrls))` if you want a simpler change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you want using `Array map` (or _.map if you must) and `Promise.all`

```
setNewCacheUrls(providedUrls: any, nativeURL: string): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all(_.map(providedUrls, url => {
        const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        return fileTransfer.download(url.url, nativeURL + url.name)
        .then((entry) => ({ name: url.name, url: entry.toURL() }));
    }));
}
```

> `_.map` - Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation function - http://underscorejs.org/#map
>
> `Promise.all` -  returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

So, the code maps `providedUrls` to the promise returned by `fileTransfer.download ... .then` - the `{ name: url.name, url: entry.toURL() }` objects.

`Promise.all` waits for all those promises to fulfill, and resolves to an array of those objects

Comment: Can you please give me a brief explanation about `_.map` and `Promise.all`?

Comment: Thanks.But how you did this `recommendationCacheUrls.push()`? i.e. how that happens in your code?

Comment: that's replaced by the `map` ... `var otherArray = []; array.forEach(item => otherArray.push(item.key));doSomething(otherArray)` is equivalent to `doSomething(array.map(item => item.key));`

Comment: Here I'm using `lodash`.Hope both functionalities are the same no (`_map()`)? I mean `underscore` and `loadsh`'s map?

Comment: yes, the result is equivalent - except lodash handles objects as well as arrays